# Sub page content rendering using vhs?

Tags: typo3, fluid

Requirement is simple , Want to render the content of sub page in main page.

Is it possible using vhs extension ?

[image]

I want to render all the sub-page content in [9]Zweckverband Parent Page.

Requirement is fully dynamic , sub-pages can increase and we need to render all the sub page content in parent [9] page.

we can render the menu using vhs , and can render the page content using vhs.
We need to combine both the coding to achieve this requirement.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can just render a menu of the subpages, but instead rendering a menu item for each of them, render their content (and maybe a headline or something). Rendering the content of an arbitrary page can be done with

```
<v:content.render pageUid="{currentPage}" column="0"/>
```

Other content retrieval viewhelpers should also have the `pageUid` parameter, so you could use them as well.

One thing that could come up is caching: If a subpage is changed, the rendering result of the main page changes. But probably TYPO3 won't recognize that, because the content on the main page itself didn't change. You might want to look into the [clearCacheCmd](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TCEmain/Index.html#clearcachecmd) and the like to solve that.

Comment: You may also search for `TYPO3 onepage` to find hints on how to solve your usecase.